# UITapGestureRecognizer and making the keyboard disappear when tapping background

Tags: ios, ios4, uikeyboard

I created a form and the keypad (Numeric only) appears when entering data like your age.

I want the keyboard to disappear when the user taps the background and I want to add a "Done" button in the empty slot under the 7 (next to the zero). (im using the Number Pad keyboard)

I found this example but I have a few questions.

In

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self                                                                       action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap]; 
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
[aTextField resignFirstResponder];
[aTextField1 resignFirstResponder];
[aTextField2 resignFirstResponder];
[aTextField3 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

If I have more than 1 text field in my form.
Will I need to write every textfield in the dismissKeyboard method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only send `dismissKeyboard` to that `textField` that you are currently editing.

In your code you have got memory leak. Better use this one:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap]; 
    [tap release];
}
```

To check if `UITextField` is currently in `edit mode` you can check its property:

**A Boolean value indicating whether the text field is currently in edit mode. (read-only)**

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isEditing) BOOL editing
```

For example, you have 3 text fields then dismissKeyboard will look something like this:

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    UITextField *activeTextField = nil;
    if ([textField1 isEditing]) activeTextField = textField1;
    else if ([textField2 isEditing]) activeTextField = textField2;
    else if ([textField3 isEditing]) activeTextField = textField3;
    if (activeTextField) [activeTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: how do I get the name of the textfield that I am currently editing?

Comment: Nekto can you show me what the dismissKeyboard method would look like?

Comment: I must be missing something. I tap the background and the Number Pad doesn't go away. Do I need to wire anything in IB?

Comment: Try to set : `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Comment: I have a TabBar application. In my first view, I've added a Scroll View and within the scroll view, I have the elements (TextFields, labels, etc). I added all the above code to the FirstViewController.h/m.

Comment: Add gesture recognizer to your scroll view

Answer (score 14):

Easy way to do this is to use the method provided in UIView

```
- (BOOL) endEditing:(BOOL)force;
```

> This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If the force parameter is set to YES, the text field is never even asked; it is forced to resign.

So just do this:

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard {
     [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

and it will support any more text fields you add on your page (under that UIView of course)

Answer (score 1):

I use the same functionality in many of my apps.  Rather than using the GestureRecognizer, I set my view up as a `UIControl`, rather than a `UIView`.  You can still do the things you'd do with a `UIView`, but you can also assign `IBActions` to be performed when interacting with the view.

Here's how to do it:
In Interface Builder, select your view.  Then, assign its class to `UIControl`. (It's probably set up as `UIView` currently.

In your ViewController for that view, write an IBAction method to detect backgroundTaps.  Mine looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender
{
    if ([textField1 isEditing]) {
        [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
    } else if ([textField2 isEditing]) {
        [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Finally, in Interface Builder, connect the IBAction you created to the `UIControl`.

Comment: i'd like to learn about using UIGestureRecognizer. I know other alternative ways (like the invisible button behind my controls).

Comment: How can I do this with view that is `UITableView` ? I can't set `UIControl` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here i give common text field object. and asign reference to it in "textFieldShouldBeginEditing"  method. that will common for all text field..

In this case, you need to dismiss one text field that will hide keyboard..

declare textfield object in .h file.

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITextField* txt_common;
}
```

IN .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap]; 
[tap release];


}

-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
NSLog(@"hi");
[txt_common resignFirstResponder];
}

#pragma mark TextField methods
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
NSLog(@"hi++++++++++++++++++");

txt_common=textField;
return YES;
}
```